# Forwarding traffic from one virtual interface to another

Tags: networking, router, linux-networking

I have a router with two ethernet interfaces:

```
eth0: 1.1.1.2 (with 1.1.1.1 gateway)
eth1: 2.2.2.1
```

I created two new virtual interfaces:

```
eth0:1 : 1.1.1.3 (with 1.1.1.1 gateway)
eth1:1 : 2.2.3.1
```

Normally, all other machines connected to the router via eth1 would have internal IP addresses 2.2.2.1/32 and 2.2.2.1 as default gateway. Then there's bunch of iptables and tc rules for traffic control. This way, all the machines connected to the router, have 1.1.1.2 as their public IP address.

I want to allow a special machine connected to the router via eth1 with 2.2.3.1 as default gateway (so actually just eth1:1) to have 1.1.1.3 as its public IP address. All the packets arriving at eth1:1 should be forwarded to eth0:1 and vice-versa.

I am using CentOS. I have IP forwarding enabled.

What iptables rule should I use for this setup?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should create a bridge using brctl and then do some packet mangling and filtering using ebtables.